# Phonegap splash screen does not work in IOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen, phonegap-cli, phonegap

I added splash.png to default root(with index.html path)
Then I added splash plugin to config.xml

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<splash src="splash.png" />
```

What is wrong with this?Why it does not show my splash.png?It shows phonegap default splash icon

Answer (score 1):

Splash screens are notoriously tricky to get right.  I've always had issues when only using the one "splash.png" image, so I recommend sizing one splash screen for your current device, then add in the others. Leverage the following sizes, making sure that the folder structure and image dimensions **match exactly**. Otherwise, the default PhoneGap one will display instead.

NOTE: The folder paths do not have to be the following: "splash/ios". Same with the file names such as "Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" - you can name them anything you want, as long as the actual filename matches!

```
<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-736h.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

<!-- iPad -->
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

<!-- Retina iPad -->
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

Comment: There is just iphone 5 and iphone 6 in your code.What about iphone 7 or other devices?especially android  has many different size..I want to use just one splash.png for all devices

Comment: The "iPhone 6" dimensions are the same for 7.  See here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html.  For Android and all others, consult the official docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/. Apologies if my answer wasn't clear: even though the PhoneGap Build docs mention just using one file, I've never got that to work, hence my answer to specify each dimension.